# strftime %F does not work on Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, visual-studio-2008, cygwin

I am trying to compile this simple example on Windows. When I use `%F`, which is a shortcut for the longer form of `%Y-%m-%d`, the process aborts with no error message. On Linux, it works fine as in [this live example shows on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/RE9Kdl). Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
   time_t rawtime;
   struct tm * timeinfo;
   char buffer [80];

   time (&rawtime);
   timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

   strftime (buffer,80,"Now it's %F.",timeinfo);
   puts (buffer);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx) has documentation on `strftime` that includes which format flags it supports.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`%F` is C99, see [strftime on man7](//man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) or compare the C99 and C90 standards yourself.

`strftime` in the VS2013 library and earlier are not C99-conformant, as they do not accept that format-specifier: [MSDN VS2013 `strftime` page](//msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx)
Maybe the next version will add it, as the format is not used for anything else yet...

Just use the format it's a shortcut to directly, that's C89 and VS2013 conformant: `%Y-%m-%d`

Quote for what happens with an invalid format specifier passed to `strftime` from the C standard:

> 6 If a conversion specifier is not one of the above, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Yes, but it shouldn't crash :)

Comment: @staticx: There's no restriction in the standard what that format-specifier does pre-C99. There's no restriction what any invalid format specifier does even post-C99 "6 If a conversion specifier is not one of the above, the behavior is undefined.". Though I wouldn't normally expect it to crash, true.

Comment: In the Linux version of strftime, it just prints out format specifiers it does not recognize. No crash. Apparently this is fixed in VS2013 or later so this may be an issue with VS2008 CRT.

Comment: That's quite reasonably sane behavior.

Comment: In VS2013SP5 it still crashes, although with a descriptive error in the debugger. But in Release mode it just crashes, most unfortunately.

Comment: Same behavior for windows cross compiler  x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++. For %T replace with %H:%M:%S.